# Beautifulsoup if class exists

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to make BeautifulSoup look for a class and if it exists then run the script? I am trying this:

```
if soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"}) == True:
    print("Tag Found")
```

I've also tried but it didn't work and gave an error about having too many attributes:

```
if soup.has_attr("div", {"class": "info"})
    print("Tag Found")
```

Comment: Is it possible to post your HTML markup or a link to the HTML? You probably don't need `== True` but otherwise your code looks OK to me.

Comment: `if soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"}):` is enough. The second attempt is incorrect.

Comment: @DYZ - Got to Give you props because I tried your code first and it worked. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're very close... `soup.findall` will return an empty list if it doesn't find any matches. Your control statement is checking its return for a literal `bool` value. Instead you need to check its truthiness by omitting the `==True`

```
if soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"}):
    print("Tag Found")
```

Comment: Easy enough! It was exactly what was needed!

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply this:

```
if soup.find("div", {"class": "info"}) is not None:
    print("Tag Found")
```

Comment: This won't work because it returns an empty list [] instead of None. Also, `None` is a singleton and should be evaluated with `is` instead of `==`. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/321861/var-is-none-vs-var-none/322394

Comment: .find will not return a list but an element, but yeas ``` if x is not None``` comes down to personal preference i guess.